# Eclipse keyboard shortcut for rename/refactor is unbinded in 2022-03

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I updated Eclipse IDE from 2021-12 to 2022-03 recently and I found out that the shortcut for rename/refactor alt-shift-r was removed.
Is this a bug and will be fixed later? Was this removed on purpose?

This was a very useful keyboard shortcut and I don't understand the 'why?' this was removed.

---

UPDATE:

This happened to me in Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20

Right click in a variable -> Refactor -> Rename... does not have a key binding anymore
[image]

Preferences: General -> Keys -> search: rename
[image]

Comment: What does the "General > Keys" Preference page show for Rename? Looks ok on my macOS Eclipse (but macOS uses different key bindings)

Comment: @greg-449 I updated my question and also found the answer. Thanks!

Comment: The problem I experienced was slightly different. For me the keybinding still existed, but pressing `Shift+Alt+R` opened the "Run" section of the eclipse window main menu instead of starting the refactoring.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The culprit was my **lombok** installation.

This bug happens when using *Eclipse 2022-03* and *lombok 1.18.22* or lower.

To fix this I needed to remove lombok. I did this by:

- deleting the "lombok.jar" file in the eclipse installation folder
- and by updated the "eclipse.ini" file in the same folder and deleting this line 
  `-javaagent:C:\Users\my-user\eclipse\latest\eclipse\lombok.jar`

Then I installed lombok-1.18.23.
To this date this release is not available in the [Download page](https://projectlombok.org/download) of lombok as a stable-release.
You can get it from here https://projectlombok.org/download-edge

Thanks to [Holger Voormann](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_6g5CvFpKUqg_dbmxsSgow) youtube channel for the answer.

This issue is followed here https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3134

Comment: Issue fixed. Migrate to lombok 1.18.24