# Eclipse IDE Alt+Shift+R refactoring shortcut for renaming not working

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, keyboard-shortcuts

**Alt+Shift+R refactoring shortcut for renaming variables sometimes not working.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse keyboard shortcut for rename/refactor is unbinded in 2022-03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71675190/eclipse-keyboard-shortcut-for-rename-refactor-is-unbinded-in-2022-03)

Answer (score 0):

**Alt+Shift+R refactoring shortcut for renaming variables sometimes not working.**

Just simply remove lombok.jar from your eclipse ide
Here is steps:

I uninstalled Lombok from Eclipse as following:

**step 1: remove Lombok.jar from Eclipse folder**

**step 2: remove 2 line from eclipse.ini (C:\Users\pcname\eclipse\jee-2022-03\eclipse)**

-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
-javaagent:lombok.jar

**Step 3: restart Eclipse**

Comment: Known lombok issue fixed in 1.18.24 (see https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3134)